# integrate ldap with cas server

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, cas

I work with cas-server-3.5.2 and I want to integrate CAS server with ldap

I try with this config,

I make in **deployerConfigContext**

this line :

```
<bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl">

        <!-- Uncomment the metadata populator to allow clearpass to capture and cache the password
             This switch effectively will turn on clearpass.
        <property name="authenticationMetaDataPopulators">
           <list>
              <bean class="org.jasig.cas.extension.clearpass.CacheCredentialsMetaDataPopulator">
                 <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentialsCache" />
              </bean>
           </list>
        </property>
         -->

        <!--
            | This is the List of CredentialToPrincipalResolvers that identify what Principal is trying to authenticate.
            | The AuthenticationManagerImpl considers them in order, finding a CredentialToPrincipalResolver which 
            | supports the presented credentials.
            |
            | AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers for two purposes.  First, it uses them to identify the Principal
            | attempting to authenticate to CAS /login .  In the default configuration, it is the DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver
            | that fills this role.  If you are using some other kind of credentials than UsernamePasswordCredentials, you will need to replace
            | DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver with a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the credentials you are
            | using.
            |
            | Second, AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers to identify a service requesting a proxy granting ticket. 
            | In the default configuration, it is the HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver that serves this purpose. 
            | You will need to change this list if you are identifying services by something more or other than their callback URL.
            +-->
        <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolvers">
            <list>
                <!--
                    | UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports the UsernamePasswordCredentials that we use for /login 
                    | by default and produces SimplePrincipal instances conveying the username from the credentials.
                    | 
                    | If you've changed your LoginFormAction to use credentials other than UsernamePasswordCredentials then you will also
                    | need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations) to declare a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the
                    | Credentials you are using.
                    +-->
                <!--<bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" >
                    <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository" />
                </bean>-->
                <bean 
     class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler"> 
     <property name="filter" value="uid=%u" /> 
     <property name="searchBase" value="DC=MINISTER,DC=FR" />  
     <property 
        name="contextSource" 
        ref="contextSource" /> 
    </bean> 
                <!--
                    | HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports HttpBasedCredentials.  It supports the CAS 2.0 approach of
                    | authenticating services by SSL callback, extracting the callback URL from the Credentials and representing it as a
                    | SimpleService identified by that callback URL.
                    |
                    | If you are representing services by something more or other than an HTTPS URL whereat they are able to
                    | receive a proxy callback, you will need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations).
                    +-->
                <bean
                    class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>



<!--
    Config CAS with LDAP
    -->
    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.util.AuthenticatedLdapContextSource"> 
 <property name="anonymousReadOnly" value="false" /> 
 <property name="pooled" value="true"/> 
 <property name="urls"> 
    <list> 
   <value>ldap://192.168.0.88:389/</value> 

    </list> 
 </property> 
 <property name="userDn" value="DC=MINISTER,DC=FR"/> 
 <property name="groupDn" value="DC=MINISTER,DC=FR"/> 
 <property name="password" value="userPassword"/> 
 <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties"> 
    <map> 
   <!--entry> 
            <key><value>java.naming.security.protocol</value></key> 
            <value>ssl</value> 
    </entry--> 
   <entry> 
    <key> 
     <value>java.naming.security.authentication</value> 
    </key> 
    <value>simple</value> 
   </entry> 
    </map> 
 </property> 
</bean>
```

and also  I make in **pom.xml**

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId> 
   <artifactId>cas-server-support-ldap</artifactId> 
   <version>3.5.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

and I make in **\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\cas-server-webapp-3.5.2\WEB-INF\lib**

cas-server-support-ldap-3.5.2.jar

but when I start cas server I have this error :

```
           ... 
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ldap/NamingSecuri
    tyException
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
    .instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:67)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
            ... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ldap.NamingSecu
    rityException
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
    der.java:1702)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
    der.java:1547)
            ... 54 more
    SafeContextLoaderListener:
    The Spring ContextLoaderListener we wrap threw on contextInitialized.
    But for our having caught this error, the web application context would not have
     initialized.
..........
```

I have already done a configuration between **ldap and liferay**  , I should use the same parameter in order to integrate **ldap with cas server**

this is my config in order to integrate ldap with liferay

**Base Provider URL**

ldap://192.168.0.88:389

**Base DN**

DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

**Principal**

CN=LDAP Requester,OU=Users,OU=Technical Accounts,OU=P9 Accounts,DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

**Credentials**

minister$9999

**Users**

**Authentication Search Filter**

(&(objectClass=person)(mail=@email_address@))

**Import Search Filter**

(objectClass=person)

**User Mapping**

**Screen Name**

sAMAccountName

**Password**

userPassword

**Email Address**

mail

**Full Name**

cn

**First Name**

givenName

**Middle Name**

middleName

**Last Name**

sn

**Group**

memberOf

**Groups**

**Import Search Filter**

(&(objectClass=group)(|(cn=MinisterUsers)(cn=MinisterAdministrateurs)(cn=Minister_*)))

**Group Mapping**

**Group Name**

cn

**Description**

sAMAccountName

**User**

member

Export

Users DN
DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

Groups DN
DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

Comment: Are CAS and Liferay running on the same application server?

Comment: no, juste I want to integrate CAS with ldap,

Comment: I dispaly the parameter of LDAP which ara used with liferay  in order to use the same parameter in my context.  the integration of LDAP with liferay is used in another application, and my goals is to integrate CAS with LDAP  in my current application which does not use liferay